# C# Properties not found on object of type

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

**Error:**

> **System.Configuration.SettingsPropertyNotFoundException** was unhandled
>       The settings property **CustomSetting** was not found.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Addsettings
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            radTextBox1.Text = (string)Properties.Settings.Default["CustomSetting"];
        }

        private void radButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property = new 
            System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("CustomSetting");
            property.SerializeAs = SettingsSerializeAs.Xml;
            property.DefaultValue = "Default";
            property.IsReadOnly = false;
            property.PropertyType = typeof(string);
            property.Provider = 
            Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"];

        property.Attributes.Add(typeof(System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute), new System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute());
            Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);

            // Load settings now.

            Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();

            // Update the user itnerface.

            Properties.Settings.Default["CustomSetting"] = radTextBox1.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line the error occurs?

Comment: radTextBox1.Text = (string)Properties.Settings.Default["CustomSetting"];

Comment: Error comes when you start the program. When I try to load text into radTextBox1.Text.

Comment: I think your application can not read Settings file. Here is an possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8404898/2050083  . Also,check if it exists.

Comment: Help me! does not work, error(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** Completely misunderstood requirement. If you're trying to create this setting at run time, then read it again later, here are the code changes:

```
//ensures no runtime errors if you try and view the setting before its created
private bool _customSettingExists = false;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //You're saving your CustomSetting to properties, so you should read it from Default.Properties
    if (_customSettingExists)
        radTextBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["CustomSetting"].ToString();
}

private void radButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Configuration.SettingsProperty property = new
    System.Configuration.SettingsProperty("CustomSetting");
    property.SerializeAs = SettingsSerializeAs.Xml;
    property.DefaultValue = "Default";
    property.IsReadOnly = false;
    property.PropertyType = typeof(string);
    property.Provider =
    Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"];

    property.Attributes.Add(typeof(System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute), new System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute());
    Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);

    // Load settings now.

    Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();

    // Update the user itnerface.

    Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["CustomSetting"] = radTextBox1.Text;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();

    //now that you know a custom setting exists
    _customSettingExists = true;
}
```

Comment: The contents of the file user
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<userSettings>
<Addsettings.Properties.Settings>
<setting name="CustomSetting" serializeAs="Xml">
<value>
<string>FFFFFFFF</string>
</value>
</setting>
</Addsettings.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
</configuration>

Comment: Your app.config looks correct. Is this being reflected in Addsettings Project? If you go to your project properties, and click on the settings tab, are all your settings coming through correctly?

Comment: App.config <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>

Comment: How to make when a user creates CustomSetting, was created in the app.config

Comment: Are you trying to create this CustomSetting at run time? and you dont have it at compile time?

Comment: The challenge is that he created automatically CustomSetting

Comment: if (_customSettingExists)
                radTextBox1.Text = (string)Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["CustomSetting"]; 

Error 1 Cannot convert type 'System.Configuration.SettingsProperty' to 'string'

Comment: Use this instead: if (_customSettingExists) radTextBox1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["CustomSetting"].ToString()

Comment: System.NullReferenceException was unhandled Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Properties.Settings.Default["CustomSetting"] = radTextBox1.Text;